# Interpretation question about between-subjects effects in multilevel modeling

Tags: interpretation, multilevel-analysis

Specific question that (of course) comes from a reviewer. In multilevel models with:

- Level2=individuals
- Level1=within-persons

Is it fair to say that, since these models explicitly estimate Level 2 variance, that the level 1 effects observed inherently "control" for **all possible** between-subjects effects? i.e., that Level 1 predictor X is associated with Level 1 outcome Y when all Level 2 factors are at their means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multilevel models, without some additional tweaks, do not control for all possible between subject effects. For a given within-person (level 1) predictor's association with the outcome, you can control for unchanging between-person factors included in your model or not that might otherwise influence the association by including the level 1 variable's mean at level 2.

Models in which you have both level 1 variables and their means as predictors are sometimes called correlated random effects models. If you instead center the level 1 variable around its level 2 (person) mean *and* include the mean at level 2 as a predictor, this is known as a between-within or 'hybrid' model. See https://www.researchgate.net/publication/299604336_Fixed_and_Random_effects_models_making_an_informed_choice and  https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1301300105. [Mundlak (1978)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1913646?seq=1) first elaborated on this idea.

These are contrasted with so-called fixed effects or no-pooling models, which account for clustering by including dummy variables for each of the individuals/groups in your data. Such models control for all non-varying between subject factors through inclusion of the dummies.